# Error when using for loop to search string array

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, exception

I'm using this code to search a string array for matches with the input, however I'm getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in task on page 110.exe

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim letters() As String = {"a", "a", "e", "g", "g", "g", "h", "g", "e", "k", "o", "k", "K", "g"}
    Dim search As String
    Dim numMatches As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        search = TextBox1.Text
        numMatches = 0
        For i = 0 To 14
            If search = letters(i) Then
                numMatches = numMatches + 1
            End If
        Next
        TextBox2.Text = numMatches
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see what the value of i is when you get the error.  I'll bet you find that it's value is 14 and that is outside the bounds of your array.

Comment: This is a trivial thing to debug.  Set a breakpoint and hold your mouse over `letters`

Comment: Remember that with 0 based arrays, an array of length n will have a max index of n-1. Thus your for loop should be from 0 to 13, or better yet to `letters.Length - 1`. Or just use a `For Each` and forget about the indexes, since you do not need them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to submit an answer with LINQ, which you can learn more about [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)

```
numMatches = letters.Select(Function(x) x).Where(Function(x) x = search).Count()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hacky, but it works this way..

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim letterslist As New List(Of String)
    Dim search As String
    Dim numMatches As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        letterslist.Clear()
        letterslist.Add("a")
        letterslist.Add("a")
        letterslist.Add("e")
        letterslist.Add("g")
        letterslist.Add("g")
        letterslist.Add("g")
        letterslist.Add("h")
        letterslist.Add("g")
        letterslist.Add("e")
        letterslist.Add("k")
        letterslist.Add("o")
        letterslist.Add("k")
        letterslist.Add("k")
        letterslist.Add("g")

        numMatches = 0

        For Each item In letterslist
            If item.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
                numMatches += 1
            End If
        Next

        TextBox2.Text = numMatches

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search for values which are outside the bounds of the array.

Arrays in vb.net start storing from 0.  So in the for loop, 0 -> 14 would search for 15 items in the array.  Changing the for loop to the code below should fix that.

```
For i = 0 To 13
            If search = letters(i) Then
                numMatches += 1
            End If
        Next
```

Another way to do this would be with a for each loop.

```
For each value in letters
        if search = value then
           numMatches += 1
        End If
   Next
```

A for each loop would still function even if you decide to change the amount of data in the array later.

*8)*